# Android string array resource: duplicate xml declaration for larger screens?

Tags: android, resources, duplicates, android-preferences, arrays

I have this string array resource in */res/values/arrays.xml*, for a ListPreference:

```
<string-array name="pref_font_size_entries">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Normal</item>
    <item>Large</item>
    <item>Extra Large</item>
</string-array>
```

If I want to add an extra list item (see the last **`<item>Huge</item>`**) on larger screens, do I have to duplicate the entire declaration in */res/values-sw600dp/arrays.xml*?

```
<string-array name="pref_font_size_entries">
    <item>Small</item>
    <item>Normal</item>
    <item>Large</item>
    <item>Extra Large</item>
    <item>Huge</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: No define the item that you want for larger screen. If the item is not in the separate xml, android will pick up default xml value.

Comment: The only difference seems to be `<item>Huge</item>` in the second arrays.xml. One alternative to duplication would be to put that in the default arrays.xml but disable it by checking screen density when you display the preferences if it isn't suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to duplicate the entire definition of `pref_font_size_entries` as they are not cumulative. Android picks the XML file which fits the resolution the best. If you have other definitions here or other XML files in /res/values which are the same for /res/values-sw600dp you don't need to duplicate those.

Comment: Ok, suppose the _arrays.xml_ file has many other resources that do not change, would you advise to move the _pref_font_size_entries_ definition (and any other related ones) into another _arrays_preferences.xml_ file, and only duplicate this smaller xml file, and not the entire _arrays.xml_?

Comment: @Jamrelian That sounds reasonable and will make the differences much more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

No need, single `/res/values/arrays.xml` is enough.

**Explanation:**

Android is smart enough. It will search for appropriate folder for resources, If not found then it will move to default folder automatically. So, If there is no difference in both file means then single file in default folder is enough.

Comment: Read his question fully. `<item>Huge</item>` is extra item into `/values-sw600dp/arrays.xml`.

Comment: It's fact that android takes appropriate resource but his question is different. He is trying to declare font size entries for different screens.

Comment: is font size did affect in default folder? I don't think so.